# File not found (Error no.2), no such directory or file

Tags: python, database, file

I'm trying to bring out all my database records using tkinter, including the stored images but having issues. My connection to my database is very okay. My codes have been working so fine until I decided to access my database rows records. I have gone through my photopath and found it okay. I also wrote an image configuration code which can be seen in my codes. Below are my codes for this:

I have gone through my code and image location path and found everything okay.
For my database table, in Mysql editor, my photo datatype is varchar(255).

When inserting my photo record in Mysql query editor, I used set photo = (c:\mycomputername\pictures\DB\Tj.jpg), I also used set photo = Tj.jpg but both still didnt work when I tried to call them in my Python code

```
import pymysql
import mysql.connector

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog

from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os
import shutil

import db_config

def on_tab_selected(event):
selected_tab = event.widget.select()
tab_text = event.widget.tab(selected_tab, "text")

if tab_text == "All Records":
    print("All records selected tab selected")
if tab_text == "Add New Records":
    print("Add new records tab selected")

def load_database_results():
global rows
global num_of_rows
try:
    con = pymysql.connect(
        host = db_config.db_server,
        user = db_config.db_user,
        password = db_config.db_pw,
        database = db_config.db
    )

    sql = "SELECT * FROM participants"
    cursor = con.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    num_of_rows = cursor.rowcount
    cursor.close()
    con.close()
    has_loaded_successfully = True
    messagebox.showinfo("Connected to Database", "Connection okay")

except pymysql.InternalError as e:
    messagebox.showinfo("Connection Error", e)
except pymysql.OperationalError as e:
    has_loaded_successfully = database_error()
except pymysql.ProgrammingError as e:
    has_loaded_successfully = database_error()
except pymysql.DataError as e:
    has_loaded_successfully = database_error()
except pymysql.IntegrityError as e:
    has_loaded_successfully = database_error()
except pymysql.NotSupportedError as e:
    has_loaded_successfully = database_error()

return has_loaded_successfully

def database_error(err):
messagebox.showinfo("Error", err)
return False

def image_path(file_path):
open_image = Image.open(file_path)
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(open_image)
return image

def load_photo_tab1(file_path):
image = image_path(file_path)
imgLabelTab1.configure(image = image)
imgLabelTab1.image = image

filename = "default.jpg"
path = db_config.PHOTO_DIRECTORY + filename

rows = "None"
num_of_rows = "None"

form = tk.Tk()
form.title("The App")
form.geometry("500x280")

tab_parent = ttk.Notebook(form)
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_parent)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_parent)

tab_parent.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>", on_tab_selected)
tab_parent.add(tab1, text = "All Records")
tab_parent.add(tab2, text = "Add New Records")

fName = tk.StringVar()
sur = tk.StringVar()
dept = tk.StringVar()

fNameTab2 = tk.StringVar()
surTab2 = tk.StringVar()
deptTab2 = tk.StringVar()
```

#WIDGETS FOR TAB1

```
firstLabelTab1 = tk.Label(tab1, text = "FirstName")
surnameLabelTab1 = tk.Label(tab1, text = "Surname")
deptLabelTab1 = tk.Label(tab1, text = "Department")

firstEntryTab1 = tk.Entry(tab1, textvariable = fName)
surnameEntryTab1 = tk.Entry(tab1, textvariable = sur)
deptEntryTab1 = tk.Entry(tab1, textvariable = dept)

#openImageTab1 = Image.open(path)
#imgTab1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(openImageTab1)                            
#replacing these three lines with the line next to them below
#imgLabelTab1 = tk.Label(tab1, image = imgTab1)    #replacing this line 
with the line just below it.

imgTab1 = image_path(path)
imgLabelTab1 = tk.Label(tab1, image = imgTab1)
btnFwd = tk.Button(tab1, text = "Forward")
btnBkw = tk.Button(tab1, text = "Backward")

#WIDGETS TO GRID ON TAB1

firstLabelTab1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 15, pady = 15)
firstEntryTab1.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 15, pady = 15)

surnameLabelTab1.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 15, pady = 15)
surnameEntryTab1.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 15, pady = 15)

deptLabelTab1.grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 15, pady = 15)
deptEntryTab1.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 15, pady = 15)

imgLabelTab1.grid(row=1, column=5, rowspan=3, padx=15, pady=15)
btnBkw.grid(row = 3, column = 0, padx = 15, pady = 15)
btnFwd.grid(row = 3, column = 2, padx = 15, pady = 15)

#WIDGETS FOR TAB2
firstLabelTab2 = tk.Label(tab2, text = "FirstName")
surnameLabelTab2 = tk.Label(tab2, text = "Surname")
deptLabelTab2 = tk.Label(tab2, text = "Department")

firstEntryTab2 = tk.Entry(tab2, textvariable = fNameTab2)
surnameEntryTab2 = tk.Entry(tab2, textvariable = surTab2)
deptEntryTab2 = tk.Entry(tab2, textvariable = deptTab2)

#openImageTab2 = Image.open(path)                                      
replacing these three lines with the line just below them
#imgTab2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(openImageTab2)
#imgLabelTab2 = tk.Label(tab2, image = imgTab2)

imgTab2 = image_path(path)
imgLabelTab2 = tk.Label(tab2, image = imgTab2)


 Another file db_config.py:

 PHOTO_DIRECTORY = "C:\\Users\\mycomputername\\Pictures\\DB\\"

 db_server = "localhost"
 db_user = "root"
 db_pw = "****"
 db = "work"
```

I am expecting a situation whereby when I run my codes, in place of the default image, the image in my database row 1, column 3 which is my photo column should show in the column but it's showing error, file not found

[theAPP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLTgg.png)

Comment: Add the error you got on running the code.

Comment: @mithlesh.kunal here's the error:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\mycomputername\\Pictures\\DB\\Tj.jpg'

Comment: If python is telling you it can't find a file, it's telling the truth. You must have a mistake in the filename.